# Caliburn Micro + DI on BL/DAL in Windows 8.1 Store app

Tags: c#, windows-8, dependency-injection, windows-8.1, caliburn.micro

I'm stuck with adding the Dependency Injection to BL/DAL layers in my Windows 8.1 Store application. I'm using Caliburn Micro 2.0.0.0 Beta with Windows 8.1 Store application. This is a sample application I'm trying to build for using CM, with a complex structure - so there's a Business Logic Layer, Data Access Layer and the Presentation layer.

The CM automatically takes care of the DI for the projects directly referenced under UI ;which is BLL. So, from the IBusinessInterface; am able to get the BLLClass instance. However, as there is no Bootstrapper for the BLL/DAL; I'm unable to inject the DALClass instance (IDataInterface type) in the Business Layer. Adding reference to DAL in the UI project will resolve the problem, but defeats the purpose of layering.

I tried adding the Bootstrapper for the libraries; but there is no BootstrapperBase to inherit from!

[image]

And the Complete source code is shared here - https://www.dropbox.com/s/5dnhs2sp3za5dj6/SampleStoreCMApp.zip

Answer (score 0):

Why does adding a reference to DAL "defeat the purpose of layering"?

You need to have your [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot) somewhere, e.g. the bootstrapper, and that needs to know about all types that has to be registered.

One solution is to delegate some of the registration process to a class in the BLL library that knows about the DAL types, but I'm not sure why you couldn't add a reference to the DAL library.

If you're using Ninject or Autofac (or similar) they have a concept of modules which can be loaded from other assemblies (they can load other modules).

Answer (score 0):

you have to also use the override

```
protected override IEnumerable<Assembly> SelectAssemblies()
        {
            var assemblies = base.SelectAssemblies();

            //locate other dlls here, I do it in my app based on the namespace and extension

            return assemblies.Concat(modules);

        }
```